# How to conditional cache results using OSB?

Tags: caching, osb, oracle-coherence

Good morning,

I'm implementing an OSB-Coherence Integration and I would like to cache results only if a condition is returned.

Example:

I have a OSB Business Service interface that return stateCode = 0 in the sucess case, otherwise it will return an error code. I wish to cache only the sucess case.

Comment: Did that answer help?

Comment: yes, it helps.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tricks you can do to switch the result cache on or off based on the *request* by inserting custom values of `<tp:cache-token>` into `$outbound/ctx:transport/ctx:request`.

However, doing conditional caching based on the result requires a different approach.

What I would do would be to create a cache wrapper proxy.

Let's say your proxy flow is currently

`MyProxy-http.proxy -> MyBusinessService-http-cached.biz`

You instead insert a bizref to a second proxy, like so:

`MyProxy-http.proxy -> MyBusinessService-sb-cached.biz -> MyBusinessService-wrapper-sb.proxy -> MyBusinessService-http.biz`

The new bizref has the cache, so you remove results caching from the old bizref.

*(So far you haven't changed anything, so the next bit is the step that does the conditional caching)*

1. You modify `MyBusinessService-wrapper-sb.proxy` to read the `$body` of the response. If it detects from the response that it shouldn't be cached, you return failure.
2. This failure will suppress result caching via the bizref.
3. If it's important to you, you can reconstitute the original message in `MyProxy-http.proxy` via a fault handler, and return it as an uncached 'success' message.